# Use Boto to get ec2 instance status

Tags: amazon-ec2, status, boto

I'm using instace.update() to get the status, which returns stopped, running or ...

But there is another status in the ec2 web interface which also shows it's initializing or ... 2/2 checks passed.

Is there a way to get the status of initializing?..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That information comes from the `DescribeInstanceStatus` request and is available in boto via the `get_all_instance_status` method.  See:

http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#boto.ec2.connection.EC2Connection.get_all_instance_status

for details.

Comment: will take a test later

Comment: Just use get_all_instance_status() to test it. It returns class boto.ec2.instancestatus.InstanceStatus object. So I can get system_status and instance_status from it. THANKS!

Comment: The **boto documentation** on this method is a little misleading -- "Retrieve all the instances in your account scheduled for maintenance", when really this can be used on **any running instances**, whether they are scheduled for maintenance or not

Answer (score 7):

EDIT:

`status=conn.get_all_instance_status(instance_ids=i-****)
print status[0].system_status.details`

  or

`print status[0].system_status.details["reachability"]`

============================================================

 OLDER: 
This might help you. It tell status about all the instances, you can use simple 'if' for filtering an instance.

```
import boto;
ec2=boto.connect_ec2()
instances= ec2.get_only_instances()
for instance in instances:
    print instance.tags['Name'] , " is ", instance.state
```